# Different results when generating random samples from kernel density

Tags: r, random, kernel-density

```
library(ks)

x<-rnorm(1000)
hist(x, col="red")

y <- rkde(kde(x), n=1000)
hist(y, col="green")

y <- rkde(density(x), n=1000)
hist(y, col="blue")
```

The last histogram is way wrong. I've used `density` before and I've found that it was accurate for far more complicated distributions. Why in this case it performs so badly? Thanks

Comment: If you're going to use non-base functions you need to tell us which package you're using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're using the function wrong.  `rkde` expects an object of the class kde.  `density` doesn't return a kde object and is structured differently.

It would be like telling somebody to shoot their pistol and handing them shotgun shells and then wondering why when they fired it didn't really do anything.

Comment: Ok. I thought `rkde` could be used to generate random samples from every kernel. I so, how can I generate random samples from a kernel obtained using `density` or other package such as `ash`?

Comment: Take a look at what rkde is doing and mimic that for an object returned by density

Comment: My purpose is not to develope a package that uses `Silverman, B. (1986)
Density Estimation for Statistics and Data Analysis
. Chapman & Hall/CRC.
London` but to use an existent function if it exists.

Comment: For something quick and dirty the following seems reasonable: `x <- rnorm(30);o <- density(x); my_samp <- sample(o$x, 1000, replace = TRUE, prob = o$y)`

Comment: Thanks for the example. I'll test it but with `replace=FALSE`.

Comment: Why would you want replace=FALSE?  By default `density` only gives 512 points where it gives you the density.  You kind of need to sample with replacement to get the histogram/curve to look like the density you're interested in.

Comment: Looking at the code for rkde it appears my method is quite close to what it's doing but they add a small amount of jitter to each sampled value.

Comment: I prefer =FALSE to avoid replicates. That jitter may be a better method to improve the fit.

Comment: You can do what you want but if you use replace=FALSE then you'll end up essentially just with a uniform distribution on the 512 points of support that density used.

Comment: If I use a high value of n in density I get accurate results.